# How to combine hooks(useEffect) with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I"m trying to see direct values of imported JSON with axios from jsonplaceholder on `<p>` element and getting type error.

To fix the problem I tried to make boolean statement (like I always did) inside the state and used `style={{ display: isLoaded ? "block" : "none" }` inside the parent element to prevent it render null.

```javascript
const [serverData, setData] = useState()
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
const [isLoaded, setLoad] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    let data = {
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
        method: "get"
    }
    //-------------------------------------------//
      requestData stand for regular axios request
    //------------------------------------------//
    requestData(data).then(res => {
        let data = res.data;
        setData(data)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}, [])

//------------------------------------------------------------//
  this should change isLoaded after changing serverData value
  if the serverData is not null it should change isLoaded to true
//-----------------------------------------------------------//
useEffect(() => {
    if (serverData) {
        setLoad(true)
    }
}, [serverData]) 

return (
    <div>
        <div style={{ display: isLoaded ? "block" : "none" }}>
            <center>
                <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Clicked me: {count} times</button>
                <br></br>
                <p>Profile id = {serverData[count].id}</p> 
                {/* ------------------------------------ */}
                {/* This work only if i do {serverData? serverData[count].id : ""} and i dont want to relay on that */}
                {/* I want to set boolean in my state and work with it like: */}
                {/* <div style={{ display: isLoaded ? "block" : "none" }}> */}
                {/* ------------------------------------ */}
                
            </center>
        </div>
        <div style={{ display: isLoaded ? "none" : "block" }}>I"m not ready yet...</div>
    </div>
)
```

I expected to prevent rendering 'null' with a Boolean secure statement on the parent element and show the value of the object inside P element but the actual results are the opposite ->
"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using CSS to hide or show, you should conditionally render otherwise the data will still be evaluated

```
const [serverData, setData] = useState()
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
const [isLoaded, setLoad] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    let data = {
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
        method: "get"
    }
    //-------------------------------------------//
      requestData stand for regular axios request
    //------------------------------------------//
    requestData(data).then(res => {
        let data = res.data;
        setData(data)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}, [])

//------------------------------------------------------------//
  this should change isLoaded after changing serverData value
  if the serverData is not null it should change isLoaded to true
//-----------------------------------------------------------//
useEffect(() => {
    if (serverData) {
        setLoad(true)
    }
}, [serverData]) 

if(!isLoaded) {
    return null;
}

return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <center>
                <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Clicked me: {count} times</button>
                <br></br>
                <p>Profile id = {serverData[count].id}</p> 
                {/* ------------------------------------ */}
                {/* This work only if i do {serverData? serverData[count].id : ""} and i dont want to relay on that */}
                {/* I want to set boolean in my state and work with it like: */}
                {/* <div style={{ display: isLoaded ? "block" : "none" }}> */}
                {/* ------------------------------------ */}

            </center>
        </div>
        <div style={{ display: isLoaded ? "none" : "block" }}>I"m not ready yet...</div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i just read today about hooks and tried it after using class only components all the time and that caused me not seeing the full picture.